# Problema com acentuação

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Estou populando uma lista em *javascript* através de uma `ViewBag`. A `ViewBag` possui uma lista de objetos e esses objetos possuem propriedades com palavras acentuadas. As mesmas estão vindo corretamente da `ViewBag`, porém quando adiciono o objeto na lista do *javascript*, as mesmas perdem a acentuação, ficando apenas caracteres estranhos.

Em uma palavra como Verificação, a mesma fica `Verifica&#xE7;&#xE3;o`.

Populo minha lista da seguinte forma:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.ListRequired)
{
    @:var required = {
    @:ExamNumber: "@item.ExamNumber",
    @:TypeName: "@item.TypeName",
    @:Description: "@item.Description"
    @:};

    @:listRequiredContent.push(required);
}
```

Tentei colocar `charset="utf-8"` na minha tag `<script>` porém não obtive sucesso.

> Existem campos na página que possuem acentuação e o texto é mostrado
>   corretamente. O problema é apenas quando tento gerenciar as
>   informações via *javascript*.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema utilizando `Html.Raw()` ao enviar textos para o *javascript*. É uma forma segura de inserir textos no *javascript*.

> O `Html.Raw()` retorna strings sem codificação em html.

- [Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

Utilizando `Html.Raw()` ao criar minha lista, a mesma ficou assim:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.ListRequired)
{
    @:var required = {
    @:ExamNumber: "@Html.Raw(item.ExamNumber)",
    @:TypeName: "@Html.Raw(item.TypeName)",
    @:Description: "@Html.Raw(item.Description)"
    @:};

    @:listRequiredContent.push(required);
}
```

Dessa forma, as palavras com caracteres especiais são inseridas corretamente no *javascript*.